# SSH multiplex one IP to many hosts?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I'm setting up a network with many linux hosts (50-200), and I would like to be able to reach all 200 hosts from one IP address and one port.

Here are the rules. Each host can have up to 20 users, but nearly all will only have 2 or 3. All authentication will be via public key. All keys are guaranteed to be unique. There can be any number of active connections at once. All hosts will have a unique internal IP to the network, and all will be listening on port 22 for SSH connections.

How do I set up a service which can handle SSH connections meant for all users on all hosts given the above constraints?

Comment: How do *you* think the "main" host can/should determine which internal host it should redirect a client to?

Comment: Some parts of your question are a little unclear, but this sounds like a common load-balancer scenario: you could use something like [haproxy](https://www.haproxy.org/) to distribute connections to your backend hosts. You'll want to ensure that all your hosts have the same host key to avoid "host key has changed" problems when clients get directed to a different backend.

Comment: Haproxy had published a whole solution: https://www.haproxy.com/blog/route-ssh-connections-with-haproxy/

Comment: @larsks this was my thought as well, but I couldn't find a suitable balancer

Comment: @TomYan since pubkey will be the only allowed auth method, it would be simple to map keys to hosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and commonly used method is to have one system act as a gateway using regular "TCP forwarding" feature of SSH. That is, you connect to the (public) host A as a normal user, set up a tunnel, and through that tunnel connect to any internal address you need.

This would be the same technology as `ssh -L` uses, but there are simpler ways to configure it without having to mess around with ports, such as `ssh -W` or the new `ssh -J` option:

```
ssh -J gatehost internalhost

# Older clients:
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p gatehost" internalhost
putty -proxycmd "plink -nc %host:%port gatehost" internalhost
```

---

Other methods are unlikely to be satisfactory. There is no TLS SNI equivalent in SSH, so unlike with sniproxy or haproxy being able to route TLS connections to different hosts based on the hostname requested, you cannot do the same with SSH.

It is not possible for the public host to see a user's public key *and* to proxy the SSH traffic to another host at the same time. User authentication is done as a later step after the encryption has already been set up (not too different from TLS/HTTPS), so the public host would need to intercept the key-exchange handshake in order to see user keys. But if I remember correctly, the user authentication stage of SSH uses a "channel binding" – it includes details about the previously done encryption handshake, *precisely* to prevent a "man-in-the-middle" attack like this – if the key-exchange was done between client and host A, but the user authentication messages somehow get forwarded to host B, the protocol will detect this.

The public host could accept user authentication like normal and just automatically 'ssh' to another host instead of starting a shell – this is doable but a basic implementation will only support interactive sessions, not SFTP, not tunnels, not agent forwarding. (Maybe there are commercial products that do this perfectly, but I expect they'd be priced according to what a huge bank or the government would pay.)